# php post method working in localhost! not working in server

Tags: php

My php file `Picture_gallery.php`:

```
 <?php
    include('connect-db.php');
    $response = array("total_records" => "", "result_returned" => "");
    $data = array("error_code" => "", "error_message" => "");
    $order = "";
    $sql = "Select * from ju_picture_gallery";
    $total_row = "";
    $result = "";
    $image_gallery = "folder_name";
    //$start_index =$_POST['start_index'];
    //$per_page =$_POST['per_page'];
    
    $folder_name = $_POST['folder_name'];
    $start_index = htmlspecialchars($_POST['start_index']);
    $per_page =htmlspecialchars($_POST['per_page']);
    
    //$folder_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['folder_name']);
    
    
    //$start_index = print_r($_POST['start_index']);
    //$per_page =print_r($_POST['per_page']);
    //$folder_name = print_r($_POST['folder_name']);
    
    if ($folder_name == "$folder_name") 
    {
        $sql = "select pg_image_url from ju_picture_gallery where folder_name ='$folder_name' LIMIT $start_index,$per_page";
        $total_row = "SELECT *  FROM ju_picture_gallery where folder_name ='$folder_name' ";
        $image_gallery = "image_gallery";
        json_encode($result);
        
        
    }
    
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $total=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$total_row));
    $response["result_returned"]=(string)$count;
    $response["total_records"]=(string)$total;
    $response["folder_name"] = (string)$folder_name;
    if ($result) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $json[] = $r;
    
        }
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($row_count > 0) {
            print json_encode(array_merge($data, array('pagination_info' => $response), array($image_gallery => $json)));
    
        } else {
            $data["error_code"] = "1012";
            $data["error_message"] = "No Content!";
            print json_encode(array_merge($data, array('pagination_info' => $response)));
    
        }
    
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Here if run this file in localhost it asks the 3 values for all the above post values.if i run in web hosing it does not asking the post values..displaying an empty sceen.
here is my webhosting link:

- [The o/p is an empty screen](http://mobileapp.jumeirahgolfestates.org/jumeirah/picture_gallery.php)
- [On this link i getting an error](http://mobileapp.certifytechnologies.com/jumeirah/picture_gallery.php)

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\certifytechnologies.com\mobileapp\jumeirah\picture_gallery.php on line 36
>
> PHP Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\certifytechnologies.com\mobileapp\jumeirah\picture_gallery.php on line 36

Comment: just turn on your error reporting on your hosting. Then you can see what errors are thrown. try this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: have you set up db on that host?

Comment: i getting the same result as before..it not working..do i need to check out any cpanel settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change some lines in your code to this

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $total_row);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


  $total=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,$count));
$response["result_returned"]=(string)$count;
$response["total_records"]=(string)$total;
$response["folder_name"] = (string)$folder_name;
if ($result) {
 while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json[] = $r;

    }
```